# How to rollback macOS Sierra Developer Beta back to El Capitan (without time machine)

Tags: macos

I can't reinstall El Capitan from AppStore because of this:

[image: error dialog]

and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> only suggest to reinstall macOS Sierra.

Comment: Golden Rule - don't put a beta OS on a mission-critical machine. Use a clone, because even Time Machine cannot roll back to an earlier OS, unless you take the precaution to remove it as you update.

Comment: In addition to the Golden Rule mentioned, one should not upgrade to a new OS without first knowing how and what it takes to revert to the previous OS and have the tools necessary in place **before** preforming the upgrade!

Comment: if you switch off SIP (System Integrity Protection), this older solution here on AskDifferent should still work: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159419/install-mavericks-on-second-partition-in-yosemite-only-system/159556#159556

Answer (score 5, accepted):

macOS is not designed to be downgradable, and as such you cannot downgrade it through an installer like this. You will need to create a bootable install disk ([Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372)), e.g. by running

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app
```

to install on a drive called MyVolume. Running this will lose you all your content, so you will need to have a backup if you want to retain your files. Otherwise, wait Sierra out…

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way is to do a Restore from Time Machine.  Your next option is to do a clean install OS X from USB or other install media; meaning wipe the HDD and install.

Comment: Topic starter wants to roll back without Time Machine.

Comment: @rwzdoorn That's from Apple and it obviously bears repeating.  There's also a second sentence to my answer.

Comment: Time machine doesn't work. You won't be able to select older installations if current is updated to latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to downgrade to El Capitan:

1. Make a new partition
2. Reboot and hold down <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd> to start Internet Recovery .
   This will clean install El Capitan.
3. After installation, remove the partition of Sierra.

See official documentation of Apple about [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314)

Done.

Comment: The Title of the question clearly states "without time machine".

Comment: Edited, this is the solution WITHOUT time machine.

Comment: @Allan, Why did you remove "Option" from the key sequence that rwzdoorn stated?

Comment: @user3439894 Because per the article he linked, it says Cmd+R, not Cmd+Option+R.

Comment: Well then, iTwister Lex already said "_and Cmd R only suggest to reinstall macOS Sierra._", so what good is this answer?  Does pressing Command+Option+R give a different choice of OS to install?

Comment: @user3439894 His tactic is to create a new empty partition (assumes there's space), install OS X there via Internet Recovery, then remove the Sierra partition.  I also assume he intends for the user to resize the new partition once done to utilize the full disk, but this is not indicated.

Comment: Okay, I actually tested this on my Mac - used Time Machine to backup & then CMD + R using the same drive (time machine) worked for me. Although during the process, the drive went off several time, but i tried doing the process all over again & it got me into El Captain.

Time Machine works, don't know of any other method which is tested & first hand verified.

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick so this helped you?

Comment: @rwzdoom, I exactly didn't use this particular method. I used time machine to backup the entire OS, and it worked. Later I found my macOS Sierra installation files (install files) saved as well in Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i just bought this macbook pro and i am really good with computers. However, this is my first mac. So the person i bought it from didnt know how to reboot it so i went online.

Command+R brings up the 4 option menu. I erased the hard drive and when i went to reinstall i wasnt able to install el capitan using my icloud id that i have for my ipad. It said temporarily not available.

So i got pissed and shut down the computer as everything i had read had not worked. After shutting it down i turned it back on and a folder with a question mark came on and couldnt get anywhere. Shut it down again.

Restarted it while holding down command+R and the internet system recovery began. Had to connect to wifi. BAMCIS it was that easy to get it to factory settings. It installed OS X LION and i then upgraded to Sierra. Only to realize that Serato Scratch live was not compatible with Sierra as i am running SL1 lol.

Anyways had to go back to OS X LION so same process erase hard drive. Shut down computer. Command+R to start internet system recovery go back to OS X Lion. Pretty simple method if you want to go back without a hastle or got a laptop off someone and are getting the temporarily not available message. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

this may seem like a bit of a hack, but you could try to use Unibeast to create a fresh OS X El Capitan installation disk, and boot your mac from it to install. 
Here is a step-by-step guide on creating this disk : 
http://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/unibeast-install-os-x-el-capitan-on-any-supported-intel-based-pc.172672/
This is basically intended for Intel-based PCs but it works like a charm on the Mac to perform rollbacks.

Comment: Why all of these down votes ? This works fine and does not need any Time Machine backups! I have already done this, it is straightforward and safe. Please kindly consider avoiding to hold the new members of the community back.

Comment: I think the community is mad at the genuine of macOS that it comes shipped with/